# Magento2: How to use Magento\Framework\Api\FilterBuilder?

Tags: magento2, filter, service-contract

I am able to use the `addFilter` in the `searchCriteriaBuilder` like this:

```
$this->searchCriteriaBuilder->addFilter(
    'name',
    'M%',
    'like'
);
```

For example in this code I can get all the product names starting with the letter M:

```
<?php

namespace Unit5\Module3\Controller\Index;

use Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaBuilder;

class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{

    /**
     * @var ProductRepositoryInterface
     */
    private $productRepository;

    /**
     * @var SearchCriteriaBuilder
     */
    private $searchCriteriaBuilder;


    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository,
        SearchCriteriaBuilder $searchCriteriaBuilder
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->productRepository = $productRepository;
        $this->searchCriteriaBuilder = $searchCriteriaBuilder;
    }


    public function execute()
    {
        $this->getResponse()->setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
        $products = $this->getProductsFromRepository();
        foreach ($products as $product) {
            $this->outputProduct($product);
        }
    }

    /**
     * @return ProductInterface[]
     */
    private function getProductsFromRepository()
    {
        $this->searchCriteriaBuilder->addFilter(
            'name',
            'M%',
            'like'
        );

        $criteria = $this->searchCriteriaBuilder->create();
        $products = $this->productRepository->getList($criteria);
        return $products->getItems();
    }

    private function outputProduct(\Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductInterface $product)
    {
        $this->getResponse()->appendBody(sprintf(
                "%s - %s (%d)\n",
                $product->getName(),
                $product->getSku(),
                $product->getId())
        );
    }
}
```

However, I have seen in some documents the use of Magento\Framework\Api\FilterBuilder. When I use that it generates this error:

> Warning: Missing argument 2 for
>   Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaBuilder::addFilter()

This is addFilter function in Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaBuilder:

```
public function addFilter($field, $value, $conditionType = 'eq')
{
    $this->addFilters([
        $this->filterBuilder->setField($field)
            ->setValue($value)
            ->setConditionType($conditionType)
            ->create()
    ]);
    return $this;
}
```

This is my code:

```
<?php

namespace Unit5\Module3\Controller\Index;

use Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaBuilder;
use Magento\Framework\Api\FilterBuilder;

class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{

    /**
     * @var ProductRepositoryInterface
     */
    private $productRepository;

    /**
     * @var SearchCriteriaBuilder
     */
    private $searchCriteriaBuilder;

    /**
     * @var FilterBuilder
     */
    private $filterBuilder;


    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository,
        SearchCriteriaBuilder $searchCriteriaBuilder,
        FilterBuilder $filterBuilder
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->productRepository = $productRepository;
        $this->searchCriteriaBuilder = $searchCriteriaBuilder;
        $this->filterBuilder = $filterBuilder;
    }


    public function execute()
    {
        $this->getResponse()->setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
        $products = $this->getProductsFromRepository();
        foreach ($products as $product) {
            $this->outputProduct($product);
        }
    }
    /**
     * @return ProductInterface[]
     */
    private function getProductsFromRepository()
    {
        $nameFilter = $this->filterBuilder
            ->setField('name')
            ->setValue('M%')
            ->setConditionType('like')
            ->create();

        $this->searchCriteriaBuilder->addFilter([$nameFilter]);

        $criteria = $this->searchCriteriaBuilder->create();
        $products = $this->productRepository->getList($criteria);
        return $products->getItems();
    }

    private function outputProduct(\Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductInterface $product)
    {
        $this->getResponse()->appendBody(sprintf(
                "%s - %s (%d)\n",
                $product->getName(),
                $product->getSku(),
                $product->getId())
        );
    }
}
```

So what is the correct way of using a FilterBuilder ?

Comment: Any luck with this, as I am facing the same issues?

Comment: No, please post here if you find the solution or thumbs up the question to capture attention.

Answer (score 1):

**Used addFilters method instead of addFilter it will worked and that's the correct way.**

```
namespace Unit5\Module3\Controller\Index;

use Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaBuilder;
use Magento\Framework\Api\FilterBuilder;

class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{

    /**
     * @var ProductRepositoryInterface
     */
    private $productRepository;

    /**
     * @var SearchCriteriaBuilder
     */
    private $searchCriteriaBuilder;

    /**
     * @var FilterBuilder
     */
    private $filterBuilder;


    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository,
        SearchCriteriaBuilder $searchCriteriaBuilder,
        FilterBuilder $filterBuilder
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->productRepository = $productRepository;
        $this->searchCriteriaBuilder = $searchCriteriaBuilder;
        $this->filterBuilder = $filterBuilder;
    }


    public function execute()
    {
        $this->getResponse()->setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
        $products = $this->getProductsFromRepository();
        foreach ($products as $product) {
            $this->outputProduct($product);
        }
    }
    /**
     * @return ProductInterface[]
     */
    private function getProductsFromRepository()
    {
        $nameFilter = $this->filterBuilder
            ->setField('name')
            ->setValue('M%')
            ->setConditionType('like')
            ->create();

        $this->searchCriteriaBuilder->addFilters([$nameFilter]);

        $criteria = $this->searchCriteriaBuilder->create();
        $products = $this->productRepository->getList($criteria);
        return $products->getItems();
    }

    private function outputProduct(\Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductInterface $product)
    {
        $this->getResponse()->appendBody(sprintf(
                "%s - %s (%d)\n",
                $product->getName(),
                $product->getSku(),
                $product->getId())
        );
    }
}
```